# Issue with records getting dropped while Calling stored proc from SQ

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping where I am calling a stored proc from SQ sql override.

```
exec up_get_unprocessed_payments
```

The stored proc is simple having a select query only.

The SQ is having all the fields which are defined in the select query of the stored proc. There is no other filter/transformations.

When the mapping is run, the stored proc outputs only 442 records(out of 446). There is no mention of dropped/rejected records in session log.
But when I run the same procedure in DB, it gives all 446 records. The interesting part, the dropped records are every 101th record.

Can you guys help here?

Comment: Are you using the same user? Did you check the connection properties?

Comment: @Maciejg yes, i am using the same user and same credentials as the connection string

Comment: Please check / post session logs. It looks as some privilige issue.

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue in lower environments, but everywhere else the mapping is working just fine. even my admin team is clueless here.

Comment: Same logic, different results? Looks like either some triggers or priviliges issue. Tried creating second stored proc with same logic?

Comment: Appears user you are using to run proc in the environment has some fewer privileges...